# Entity Framework changing connection string with c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an app that the connection string changes by per user and machine. that said I have made a test connection string just to get it testing. Then once that is working I will add the dynamic connection string.

After some research I have figured out that there is a problem with the connection string.

If someone could please tell me where I am wrong I would appreciate it.

```
var s = @"metadata=res://*/ProcurementModel.csdl|res://*/ProcurementModel.ssdl|
          res://*/ProcurementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
          provider connection string=&';data source=JAMES-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=User;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&';";
```

Update:

```
public ProcurementContext()
{
    var s =
            @"metadata=res://*/ProcurementModel.csdl|res://*/ProcurementModel.ssdl|
            res://*/ProcurementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
            provider connection string=&';data source=JAMES-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=jd;password=P@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&';";

    _connectionString = s;
}
```

Getting data:

```
public List<Procurement> ParcelListByUser(string userName)
{
    using (var context = new ProcurementEntities(_connectionString))
    {
        return context.Procurements.Where(p => p.UserName == userName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Constructor:

```
public ProcurementEntities(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

Error message:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 165.

Configuration:

The configuration of the Procurement

```
public class ProcurementConfiguration:DbConfiguration
{
    public ProcurementConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory(ConnectionStrings.LocalConnectionString));
    }
}
```

Comment: `connection string=&';` looks wrong. should probably be something like `connection string="`?

Comment: how do you set this string? i mean, how do you use the string "s"?

Comment: can you detail how you ProcurementEntities constructor is made?

Comment: referring to your error: which dbms are you using? Sql server? which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in your connection string. I've made the same thing and I have a function to create the connection string in an automatic way.

The code:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // Build the provider connection string with configurable settings
        string cn = "server=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbServer;
        cn += ";database=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbName;
        cn += ";uid=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbUser;
        cn += ";pwd=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbPassword + ";";
        var providerSB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cn);
        var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        // or the config file based connection without provider connection string
        efConnection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        efConnection.ProviderConnectionString = providerSB.ConnectionString;
        // based on whether you choose to supply the app.config connection string to the constructor
        efConnection.Metadata = @"res://*";  //-----> very important
        return efConnection.ToString();
    }
```

In this way, I pass the return value to my db context constructor, like in your code. My constructor is:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Try it and ask if you have some problem.

Comment: where do you implement the GetConnectionString()? before you call Entities?

Comment: I use it in this way: dbContext = new Entities(GetConnectionString());

Comment: this works for me with SQL Server, with version from 2008 to 2014 (never tested 2016, but I think it's ok too)

Answer (score 0):

One way to change your connection string dynamically is to only change entity framework underlying connection's connection string. Something like this:

```
myDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data source=JAMES-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=DynamicUser;password=DynamicPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFrameworkForUser";
```

This way, your application does not have to hardcode tokens related to entity framework (i.e. metadata).